# C# HtmlElement JavaScript won't set InnerHtml

Tags: c#, javascript

I made HtmlElement instance using the tag 'script' and it wont allow me to set the InnerHtml member.

Why is that?

```
HtmlElement tempElement = wbMain.Document.CreateElement("script");

wbMain.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0].AppendChild(tempElement);

tempElement.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
tempElement.InnerHtml = "function test(a){document.getElementById('test').value = a;}";
```

The end goal of this is to inject JavaScript code into a webpage and execute it from the application using the InvokeScript function in the webbrowser form's htmldocument

Answer (score 3):

You really should be using the `Page.ClientScript` methods.

ex :

```
string myScript = "function test(a){document.getElementById('test').value = a;}";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( typeof( Page ), "someScriptName", myScript, true );
```

Comment: I dont see how I can use that, is it for WPF? Im using forms

Comment: Not sure about WPF, but it's for Web Forms.  What framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[HtmlElement.InnerHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml.aspx)

*Some tags, such as the SCRIPT tag, can only contain text content; setting InnerHtml will result in an error.*

Comment: Setting the OuterHtml or OuterText doesnt do anything, but doesnt throw an exception either. InnerText does throw an exception.

Comment: Just trying to answer the "Why is that" portion of your question :)

Comment: A solution would help more o: